# How to fill df with data from another df - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fill df with values form a different one.

The first df is:

[image: image description here]

The second df is:

[image: image description here]

I want to add the column to first df having values from the second one to receive output:

| number | trans | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HF01 | one | sty | 1 |
| HF01 | one | lut | 2 |
| - | - | - | - |
| HF05 | five | paz | 50 |

I came up with code:

```
found = []

for index, row in one.iterrows():
    for ind, rw in two.iterrows():
        if ind not in found:
            if (one.loc[index, 'number'] == two.loc[ind, 'number']) & \
               (one.loc[index, 'trans'] == two.loc[ind, 'trans']) & \
                    one.loc[index,'value'] =  two.loc[ind, one.loc[index, 'date']]
                    found.append(int(ind))
                    break
```

It works but it is extremely slow. How it should be done properly?

Comment: Try to first use `pandas.melt` to convert the data from wide to long format, then use `pandas.merge` to join the two tables together to get the output you want.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the tip. That is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

First answers is close, the only thing you need to do is merge both data frames using two fields. You do not need both data frames to have the same length at all

Try:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ["number","trans"], how = "left")
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for looking at it. In this case pandas.melt does the job. I wanted data to be in a long format not wide.